# How to let the .bashrc know the current operation system

Tags: linux, bashrc

I have several linux computers sharing one disk and one home folder.

That is on the disk, there is the home folder: `\home\wuciawe`

And for computer A, whose os is Centos, it will load `\home\wuciawe\.bashrc`

For computer B, whose os is Ubuntu, it will load `\home\wuciawe\.bashrc`, same with computer A.

Because I am not the Admin, I build and install some software locally on Ubuntu, and add something to the Path in `\home\wuciawe\.bashrc`.

Due to some reason, something added to the Path draw a contradiction with Centos.

I wonder if there is a way to let the .bashrc know the current system, do something like follows:

```
if os is Ubuntu:
  Path = xxx:$PATH
  export PATH
endif
```

Comment: You can use the information here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35183/how-do-i-identify-which-linux-distro-is-running I wouldn't actually bother trying to parse these though. You should be able to simply check for the existence of files like `/etc/redhat-release` to determine if it is Red Hat, for example.

Comment: I normally have scripts which are hostname specific. e.g : 

    `case $HOSTNAME in pc1|pc1)`
  
as I cant find reliable way to find OS across all linux distros, mac + cygwin,

Comment: @NeilWightman This method looks greater as it can specify different computers with same os.

Comment: I normally use a combination of `case $HOSTNAME` and `case $TERM` for all the combinations I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Ubuntu

```
if grep -i Ubuntu /etc/lsb-release &>/dev/null
then
  export PATH=xxx:$PATH
fi
```

#### Notes

- In shell, there is no colon at the end of an `if` statement.
- In shell, you do not want spaces on either side of an equal sign in an assigment statement.
- In shell, `if` statements are concluded with an `fi` statement

#### CentOS

There is an analogous solution for CentOS:

```
if grep -i CentOS /etc/centos-release &>/dev/null
then
  export PATH=xxx:$PATH
fi
```

Comment: The release file may not reside at `/etc/lsb-release`.  On RH-like systems it's `/etc/redhat-release`.

Comment: @CongMa Very true.  If you are interested in more general solutions that handle a variety of distributions, see, for example, [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6348/53604).  The simple code above was intended to answer the OP's specific question about a test for Ubuntu.

Comment: The OP seems to want something for both CentOS and Ubuntu.  In that case, it would be fine just checking both paths.

Answer (score 1):

You could try grepping the `/etc/issue` file for OS names.  The file's content is used by `getty` to display a pre-login message.  From the man page of `issue(5)`:

> The  file  /etc/issue is a text file which contains a message or system identification to be printed before the login prompt.  It  may  contain various  @char and \char sequences, if supported by the getty-type program employed on the system.

Please see @John2014's post about how to grep it in a shell script.

Comment: since John's answer is complete, I accept his. And as well, I vote for your answer because it's more general.

Comment: It is common advice to sysadmins, [see here for example](http://help.unc.edu/help/how-to-secure-a-redhat-linux-system/), to remove any identifying OS information from `/etc/issue`.  So, use this approach with caution.